# Adding S3DistCp to PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, s3distcp

I'm trying to add S3DistCp to my local, standalone Spark install. I've downloaded S3DistCp:

```
aws s3 cp s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.latest/s3distcp.jar .
```

And the AWS SDK as well:

```
wget http://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip
```

I extracted the AWS SDK:

```
unzip aws-java-sdk.zip
```

Then added `s3distcp.jar` to my `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/mark.miller/.ivy2/jars/s3distcp.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /Users/mark.miller/.ivy2/jars/s3distcp.jar
```

Then I added the AWS SDK and all it's dependencies to $LIBJARS and $HADOOP_CLASSPATH

```
export $LIBJARS=/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/aspectjweaver.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/freemarker-2.3.9.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/ion-java-1.0.1.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/javax.mail-api-1.4.6.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/jmespath-java-1.11.86.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/joda-time-2.8.1.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/json-path-2.2.0.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/spring-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar,/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/spring-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$LIBJARS
```

But when I try to start the pyspark shell:

```
$ pyspark
```

I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/02/06 17:48:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/06 17:48:50 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 307, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 179, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 246, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.cache.LocalCache
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.<init>(LocalCache.java:4867)
        at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:785)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2373)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2373)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2373)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I remove s3distcp.jar from `spark-defaults.conf` the error goes away. There just doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to deploy this since it's provided as part of EMR.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you need to add the s3distcp jar inside your spark app ? You can do the same with regular spark.

Comment: I am using AWS EMR as a plaform and I'm concerned about partition size of files being written to S3 (small files problem). My understanding is that many small files cause performance problems. I want to combine the `--groupBy` and `--targetSize` parameters to ensure we do not have large numbers of small files. I'm trying this route after finding recommendations that this is the optimal way to transfer files between EMR clusters and S3. Admittedly I'm a noob, so please instruct me.

Comment: You know that s3distcp relies on hadoop MR under the hood so the small file problem will still persist whether your are loading data with spark or s3distcp and also you can always use s3distcp before the spark app. This way you can copy the data to EMR which you need to put on HDFS

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain well. What I mean is that I want to use s3distcp when I write my output to s3 so that the performance of future reads can be optimized. The job is transforming raw input and partitioning it so that it can be processed downstream. I am trying to optimize read performance by reducing the number of files to be read by the downstream jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by passing `--driver-class-path` to `pyspark`:

```
$ pyspark \
 --driver-class-path \
 ~/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86.jar:\
 ~/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/*
```

To set this up in `spark-defaults.conf` I had to do it this way:

```
spark.jars /Users/mark.miller/.ivy2/jars/s3distcp.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86.jar:/Users/mark.miller/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.11.86/third-party/lib/*
```

I also learned that `spark.executor.extraClassPath` is only needed for backwards-compatibility with older versions of spark (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)